# Insert Documents to specific ID in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

i am trying to insert a document into a specific ID (ID generated Default by mongoDB) like we do in  mysql  (INSERT WHERE id="985264").

```
app.get('/', function(req , res){
db.facebook.insert({
_id:985264,
 username: "Solomon.david",
 status : "i love to code and eat",
 comments: [
{
  user : "jackson",
  comment: "even me "
}
]
  }, function(err,docs){
 res.render('won.html');     
  });
});
```

Comment: I have never seen `INSERT WHERE` before, unless you are describing an INSERT INTO ... SELECT`.  What do you mean "into a specific ID".  What goes wrong when you do what you are trying?  What have you done to try to solve it?

Comment: i am trying to create a comment system when a user submits his/her comment to a specific photo with a unique ID (which the mongoDB creates by default ) it should inserted in to that particular photo

Comment: @Solomondavid I have addressed your requirement of adding comments to a particular photo in my answer. You can refer it if you are still looking for it.

Comment: this question is.... badly written.... The chosen answer doesn`t even answer what the title is asking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per your comment:

> i am trying to create a comment system when a user submits his/her
>   comment to a specific photo with a unique ID (which the mongoDB
>   creates by default ) it should inserted in to that particular photo –

1. I understand that you have a photos collection where each photo as a unique ID.
2. When the user submits a comment to a specific photo that comment must be inserted in that photo

It's a typical update operation, as you will be updating the photo document with the comment being inserted in the array.

```
{
   _id :  ObjectId("536f710fc55b2acc61000bc9"),
   foo: "foo",
   bar : "bar",
   comments: [
   {
      user : "userId",
      comment: "The photo is nice"
   }
   ]
}
```

So your query will be:

```
db.photocollection.update(
   {_id: ObjectId("536f710fc55b2acc61000bc9")},
   {$push : {
             comments : {
               user: "userid",
               comment: "photo is awesome"
               }
          }
    }
)
```

All the comments are inserted in the same photo document.

> Note: If you feel that the number comments will grow a lot over time,
>   then its better to reference the comments instead of embedding.

Hope its useful to you!

Comment: i was exactly looking for this answer

Comment: No.. this will add new comments to the photo post

Comment: If you want to edit the existing comment, then first do $elemMatch and then get the position of it. then use positional operator $ to update the comment.

Comment: great! enjoy @Solomondavid:)

Comment: when i tried  your query  above with update method with console it works fine but with node.js and express it inserts twice in to the db.

Comment: Perfect answer for insert where query. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 11):

All you have to do is specify the `_id` attribute within the document you are trying to insert:

```
db.collection.insert( { "_id": "unique_id", "foo": "bar", ... } )
```

As mentioned in [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#id-field), there are a few considerations that you should take care to enforce - namely, you need to ensure that the `_id` you have specified is unique.

---

Taken from the linked documentation page:

> If the document does not specify an _id field, then MongoDB will add
>   the _id field and assign a unique ObjectId for the document before
>   inserting. Most drivers create an ObjectId and insert the _id field,
>   but the mongod will create and populate the _id if the driver or
>   application does not.
>
> If the document contains an _id field, the _id value must be unique
>   within the collection to avoid duplicate key error.

Comment: it shows duplication ID in error report can u post  me an example code of comment system

Comment: Well... as is mentioned **twice** in my answer, you have to ensure that the `_id` you are trying to insert is unique. There is no example code to provide here - it is as it appears in the code I have posted and in the documentation.

Comment: @Lix The OP wants to insert comment to a specific photo, Which is like embedding comments within the Photo collection. But your answer only shows to insert comment but it fails to show how its linked to a particular photo

Comment: @moh - you might be correct, but my answer only addresses the actual question that was asked. What the OP does with this information is not really part of this post. Your answer is in reply to a comment and not an actual question post.

Comment: @Lix yes, you are correct. The OP didn't mention that in the question, but just mentioned it in the comments below.